# How to reverse the rows in a table?

Tags: table-field, table

I could do with flipping the rows in a table, within a template. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reverse](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/reverse.html) it!

```
<ul>
    {% for row in entry.myTableFieldHandle|reverse %}
        <li>{{ row.columnHandle }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```